# Using a PHP login on a SSL-encrypted site

Tags: php, ssl

I have been using [this login 'template'](https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal) for a while now on one of my websites that have no SSL certificate.

When I was trying to setup the same login template on my site that has RapidSSL, it gives me a 403 error when I click the login button. It's connected to the same database and the files are the same so it shouldn't be a difference, really.

Does having a SSL certificate complicate login websites somewhat?

Tried using it on another site that has no certificate aswell and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally yes, SSL does complicate things a little. That's the point right.
You are using code from a GitHub project, you should first post a question to the development team there if the documentation does not point you in the right direction.

I can't really offer you more assistance here unless you post some related code.

I have posted this as an answer so that it has a lot more prominence than a comment, and truly the answer is, to contact the developers first when you have issues implementing projects sourced from GitHub. That particular project looks pretty active, there is only 1 unanswered issue and there are many forks.

So please look there for guidance.